# multiple comparison with a binomial model in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, multiple-comparisons

When performing a multiple comparison in a binomial model, I encounter a problem when one of the groups has the probability of success = 1. For example,

```
y <- c(1,5,9,10)
N <- c(10,10,10,10)
x <- factor(c(1,2,3,4))
dat <- data.frame(y,N,x)
model <- glm(cbind(y,N-y)~x,family=binomial,data=dat)
library(multcomp)
summary(glht(model, mcp(x="Tukey")))
```

Gives an output of

```
         Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: glm(formula = cbind(y, N - y) ~ x, family = binomial, data = dat)

Linear Hypotheses:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
2 - 1 == 0     2.197      1.229   1.787    0.233  
3 - 1 == 0     4.394      1.491   2.948    0.012 *
4 - 1 == 0    27.316  54605.919   0.001    1.000  
3 - 2 == 0     2.197      1.229   1.787    0.233  
4 - 2 == 0    25.118  54605.919   0.000    1.000  
4 - 3 == 0    22.921  54605.919   0.000    1.000  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

In this example, group 4 has 10 successes in 10 trials, and the P-value for the comparison with group 4 is all 1. How can I deal with this problem?